# Minimal Transaction in Sandbox fails: Fatal error: The operation ... is outdated and may never be included in the chain

Tags: transfer, sandbox, bootstrapping, blockexplorer

I'm tying to get a simple transaction in the sandbox running. Everything according to tutorials on the main site ([Tezos Client](https://assets.tqtezos.com/docs/setup/1-tezos-client/) and [Sandbox](https://assets.tqtezos.com/docs/setup/2-sandbox/))

The error is according to this and this solved by timestamping and bootstrapping it. So I made sure I did both too before starting the transactions:
["Operation is outdated and may never be included in the chain"](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/985/operation-is-outdated-and-may-never-be-included-in-the-chain) - I got the message it's bootstrapped and did `tezos-client get timestamp`.
The proposed solution for [Node synchronization](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/661/node-synchronization/662#662) doesn't work for me as I'm not doing it in the main network and the proposed page https://www.tzdutch.com/quicksync/ gives me an Error 404.

Any ideas on what am I supposed to do?

```
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ wget https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/releases/latest/download/tezos-client
--2020-05-11 09:53:47--  https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/releases/latest/download/tezos-client
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.118.4
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.118.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/releases/download/202004061400/tezos-client [following]
--2020-05-11 09:53:47--  https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/releases/download/202004061400/tezos-client
Reusing existing connection to github.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/219989982/22ff6d00-7816-11ea-990e-afdb996e9e7b?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20200511%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200511T095558Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=11981313ba4e6f383f7b8fde04048df38c4f3b0a232d0ea24868d75b8c65e308&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&repo_id=219989982&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dtezos-client&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream [following]
--2020-05-11 09:53:48--  https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/219989982/22ff6d00-7816-11ea-990e-afdb996e9e7b?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20200511%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200511T095558Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=11981313ba4e6f383f7b8fde04048df38c4f3b0a232d0ea24868d75b8c65e308&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&repo_id=219989982&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dtezos-client&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
Resolving github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com (github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.216.237.139
Connecting to github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com (github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com)|52.216.237.139|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12690180 (12M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'tezos-client'

tezos-client                                                        100%[===================================================================================================================================================================>]  12.10M  6.98MB/s    in 1.7s    

2020-05-11 09:53:50 (6.98 MB/s) - 'tezos-client' saved [12690180/12690180]

qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ chmod +x tezos-client
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ alias tezos-client=$PWD/tezos-client
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ docker run --rm --name my-sandbox --detach -p 20000:20000        registry.gitlab.com/tezos/flextesa:image-tutobox-run carthagebox start
Unable to find image 'registry.gitlab.com/tezos/flextesa:image-tutobox-run' locally
image-tutobox-run: Pulling from tezos/flextesa
c9b1b535fdd9: Pull complete 
91014b6da692: Pull complete 
6c49ce47dfa3: Pull complete 
5e3c53d04a40: Pull complete 
ce2490f919f6: Pull complete 
ef8ab0dc3b56: Pull complete 
e525f2bb759f: Pull complete 
e24153b16357: Pull complete 
483a5c105fd1: Pull complete 
abe934830749: Pull complete 
aab7c851c9e5: Pull complete 
c6375e188145: Pull complete 
da81d144edda: Pull complete 
260967aa60cd: Pull complete 
3b1d0f32f719: Pull complete 
ba46195f3e10: Pull complete 
9ff8d086011e: Pull complete 
43876a893121: Pull complete 
5c997d42e932: Pull complete 
745447fee0e1: Pull complete 
1e12b86b834f: Pull complete 
f9f4c936e771: Pull complete 
4ebed9505434: Pull complete 
00ee75f3d997: Pull complete 
700907a1143f: Pull complete 
e9314af257c2: Pull complete 
334545ddce88: Pull complete 
dad97c6536ab: Pull complete 
83da6bd6167a: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:a90beea07f3bfa16ef2febfb2340a8c51d14660b72ad7f415dab12ecd960b22a
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/tezos/flextesa:image-tutobox-run
ae27582cfcd6610ef6a757394e99a44613b3ea362625aac637e9deb1ea262781
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                      NAMES
ae27582cfcd6        registry.gitlab.com/tezos/flextesa:image-tutobox-run   "carthagebox start"      11 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       0.0.0.0:20000->20000/tcp                                                   my-sandbox
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ tezos-client config reset
Warning:

   The node you are connecting to claims to be running in a
                    Tezos TEST SANDBOX.
      Do NOT use your fundraiser keys on this network.
  You should not see this message if you are not a developer.

qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$  export TEZOS_CLIENT_UNSAFE_DISABLE_DISCLAIMER=yes
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ tezos-client -A localhost -P 20000 bootstrapped
Current head: BMQyNEnZfJRo (timestamp: 2020-05-11T09:55:13-00:00, validation: 2020-05-11T09:55:16-00:00)
Bootstrapped.
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ tezos-client -A localhost -P 20000 config update
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ tezos-client get timestamp
2020-05-11T09:55:38Z
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ date
Mon May 11 09:56:00 UTC 2020
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ tezos-client import secret key alice unencrypted:edsk3QoqBuvdamxouPhin7swCvkQNgq4jP5KZPbwWNnwdZpSpJiEbq --force
Tezos address added: tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ tezos-client import secret key bob unencrypted:edsk3RFfvaFaxbHx8BMtEW1rKQcPtDML3LXjNqMNLCzC3wLC1bWbAt --force
Tezos address added: tz1aSkwEot3L2kmUvcoxzjMomb9mvBNuzFK6
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ docker run --rm registry.gitlab.com/tezos/flextesa:image-tutobox-run carthagebox info
Usable accounts:

- alice
  * edpkvGfYw3LyB1UcCahKQk4rF2tvbMUk8GFiTuMjL75uGXrpvKXhjn
  * tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb
  * unencrypted:edsk3QoqBuvdamxouPhin7swCvkQNgq4jP5KZPbwWNnwdZpSpJiEbq
- bob
  * edpkurPsQ8eUApnLUJ9ZPDvu98E8VNj4KtJa1aZr16Cr5ow5VHKnz4
  * tz1aSkwEot3L2kmUvcoxzjMomb9mvBNuzFK6
  * unencrypted:edsk3RFfvaFaxbHx8BMtEW1rKQcPtDML3LXjNqMNLCzC3wLC1bWbAt

Root path (logs, chain data, etc.): /tmp/mini-box (inside container).
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ tezos-client get balance for "alice"
2000000 ꜩ
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ tezos-client get balance for "bob"
2000000 ꜩ
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ tezos-client transfer 100 from "alice" to "bob" -fee 0.00
Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
Estimated gas: 10207 units (will add 100 for safety)
Estimated storage: no bytes added
Fatal error:
  The proposed fee (ꜩ0) are lower than the fee that baker expect by default (ꜩ0.001281).
   Use `--force-low-fee` to emit this operation anyway.
qoheletal@ubuntu1604:~/$ tezos-client transfer 100 from "alice" to "bob" -fee 0.00 --force-low-fee
Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
Estimated gas: 10207 units (will add 100 for safety)
Estimated storage: no bytes added
Operation successfully injected in the node.
Operation hash is 'oogpJFBAMSKJsjAJc1Jrex6xPewyngRqcYoGqgdh6yAdMLQTpdw'
Waiting for the operation to be included...
Fatal error:
  The operation oogpJFBAMSKJsjAJc1Jrex6xPewyngRqcYoGqgdh6yAdMLQTpdw is outdated and may never be included in the chain.
  We recommand to use an external block explorer.
```

Answer (score 0):

> `tezos-client transfer 100 from "alice" to "bob" -fee 0.00 --force-low-fee`

This is normal, if you force `0` fee, none of the bakers picks up your operation and at some point it becomes "obsolete" (= the blocks it's based on is too old).

Comment: What would be the correct command?

Comment: Something like `tezos-client transfer 100 from "alice" to "bob" ` ?

Comment: Remove "-fee 0.00" and "--force-low-fee". Just let the client use the defaults. The defaults are already extremely low for fee calculations.